# Embed Keynote presentation on website

Tags: ms-office, keynote, websites

Is there any way to get a Keynote presentation up on the web somewhere? There are things like [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/), but they seem to only work with PowerPoint.

I see that Keynote provides a variety of export options, but each one is problematic in one way or another:

- PowerPoint: things get cropped weird, transitions are awful
- HTML: weird DHTML format that only seems to work in Safari
- PDF: not really a presentation
- Quicktime: umm... no

My presentation has a lot of precise formatting and transitions (nothing too over the top, but things do move around) that I'd like to preserve. Also presenter's notes would be nice.

Is there anything out there that I can use?

Comment: Screen recording the presentation, then uploading as .mp4. YouTube is your best friend.

Comment: Does it need to be embedded, or just online?

Comment: This is a pretty old thread, so I no longer need an answer. But for the sake of conversation, YouTube or another video solution will not work. I need to preserve the ability to advance slides at the user's discretion.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is No. I have been looking for weeks. I have tried many programs, read many articles, and even called apple. Apple said, "We do not make our software with web development in mind."

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but the latest updates (this week) to Keynote actually do allow you to embed a Keynote. This is Keynote 7.1 for Mac and Keynote 3.1 for iOS.

The features are *very* limited. Your slideshow can't do anything complex, including transitions and builds. But, it seems to work pretty well. Getting the embed code is a little tricky, so I built a simple little tool for getting it here:

https://keynoteiframe.com

You should be able to embed Keynote slides anywhere that allows iframes.